# Understanding the definition of viscosity solutions

Tags: viscosity-solutions

I am thinking about the definition of viscosity solutions. One is interested in pde's of the form

$F(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))=0$ in $\Omega$

for some $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Later in most books there arises at some point the discussion of viscosity solutions for

$F(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))=f(x)$ in $\Omega$

for some $f$.
But in the definition of viscosity solutions there is a "$0$" required on the right hand side.
Is this because of

$F(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))=f(x)$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $F(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))-f(x)=0$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\hat{F}(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x)) =0$

and the $f(x)$ term is just seen as an expression of "x" and thus one gets a new function $\hat{F}$?

Comment: Do not vandalize your post.  Someone took the time to answer your question, and future readers might find value in either the question or answer.  Vandalizing your post is disrespectful to that answerer, and to potential future readers.

Comment: Please do not edit your post in order to change its meaning after it has been answered.  This creates a moving target for answerers, and has the potential to invalidate answers which have already been provided.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Hi! Sorry - I didn't see your comments here made yesterday. Could you please delete my two other questions I wanted to edit (Uniform convergence via Arzela-Ascoli and Uniquiness of solution for second order differential equation with two Dirichlet conditions)? I don't want them to exist anymore (for quite important reasons), please delete them (if fine for those who commented), I didn't know how to contact you directly so I had do comment here! Thank you :-) I'm gonna delete this comment when you read it.

Comment: Once you post a question to SE, that question belongs to the community here.  Generally speaking, we will not delete questions simply because the original asker no longer wants it to appear on the site.  You may request dissociation.  Details can be found [on the main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which books are you referring to? It would be peculiar to see
$$F(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))=f(x) \ in \ \Omega,$$
Since the $f(x)$ on the right hand side is redundant, as $F$ is allowed to depend on $x$.

If you put $f(x)$ on the right hand side, usually you are specifying how the $x$-dependence arises, and that it is additive and does not involve $u$ or its derivatives. I would expect you to see
$$H(u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))=f(x) \ \ in \  \Omega.$$
Note $H$ does not depend on $x$. This is equivalent to $F=0$ where $F$ is given by
$$F(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x)) = H(u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))-f(x).$$